# Laravel 4: Mail Send with array to CC gives error of does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

This drive me crazy all the time...
I tried read all the stuff regarding SwiftMailer for Laravel including fixes from other errors base on **subject**, but I do not get how I am still getting error passing array of email address.

Is there a way to determine how the CC display my email addresses? Whenever I `print_r` it, it display `“name@domain.com; name2@domain.com “`.

```
// current logged id
$user_id = $id;

// match all current logged id to all assets
// if investment type is present, get property id
$asset = ClientPropertyManagement::where('assets.client_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

foreach( $asset as $assets ) {
  if( $assets->investment_type == "TIC"  ) {
    $properties[] = $assets->property_id; 
  }
}

// if property id is present, connect to property table
// if connected and match id, get property manager emails
if( !empty($properties) ){
  $property = DB::table('property')->whereIn('id', $properties)->get();
  foreach( $property as $p ){
    $contact[] = $p->property_mgmt_contact;
  }
}

// if property managers are present, filter
// name@domain.com; name2@domain.com
if( !empty($contact) ) {
  $property_contact = implode(', ', array_filter(array_unique($contact)));
}

print_r($property_contact);
// output: "name@domain.com; name2@domain.com "

//send email to owner and other property manager                
Mail::send('_dash.emails.profile', $contacts, function ($message) {                             
  $ownerEmail = "name@gmail.com";
  $ownerName = "WebMail Information";
  $recipient_name  = Request::get('firstname') .' '. Request::get('lastname');
  $recipient_email = explode(';', Input::get('email'));

  $message->from($recipient_email[0],$recipient_name);
  $message->cc($property_contact); // send property all managers
  $message->to($ownerEmail,$ownerName)->subject("Profile Update");                 
});
```

Note: After I dump `dd($property_contact)` the value was `null`... how come? Even if I paste the code inside `Mail::send` still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `use ($variable)` inside my `Mail::send` to pass my variable outside `Mail::send`.

```
//send email to owner and other property manager                
Mail::send('_dash.emails.profile', $contacts, function ($message) use ($property_contact) {                             
  $ownerEmail = "name@gmail.com";
  $ownerName = "WebMail Information";
  $recipient_name  = Request::get('firstname') .' '. Request::get('lastname');
  $recipient_email = explode(';', Input::get('email'));

  $message->from($recipient_email[0],$recipient_name);
  $message->cc($property_contact); // send property all managers
  $message->to($ownerEmail,$ownerName)->subject("Profile Update");                 
});
```